# How to set Category Label for dynamic stacked column chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-dataviz

I am building a stacked column chart.  I don't know the number of series going into it so I am using a **foreach** to build each series.  I want a category label for each of the series.  Typically for something like this I would use the **categoryexpression** but can't figure out how to do it with the way I am building.  Here is what it looks like w/o the labels, just for reference to code.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart()

.Name("chart")

.Theme("flat")

.Title("Issues Waterfall")

.DataSource(ds => ds

    .ServerOperation(false)

)

.Series(series =>

{

    series.Column(new double[] { 100 }).Name("Total").Color("Blue").Stack("Total");



    foreach (var resp in Model.listResponsibleDowntime)

    {

        series.Column(new double?[] { resp.percent_pad }).Name(resp.resp_name).Color("White").Opacity(0).Labels(false).Tooltip(false).Stack(resp.resp_name);

        series.Column(new double?[] { resp.percent_downtime }).Name(resp.resp_name).Color(resp.resp_color).Labels(lables => lables.Format("{0:n2}%").Visible(true).Position(ChartBarLabelsPosition.OutsideEnd)).Stack(resp.resp_name);

    }



    series.Column(new double?[] { Model.oee }).Name("Actual").Color("Green").Stack("Actual").Labels(lables => lables.Format("{0:n2}%").Visible(true).Position(ChartBarLabelsPosition.OutsideEnd));



})

.CategoryAxis(axis => axis

    .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))

    .Labels(model => model

        .Rotation(0)

        .Visible(true)

    )

    //.Categories(Model.listCategories)

)

.Legend(legend => legend

    .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Top)

    .Margin(20, 50, 20, 50)

    .Visible(false)

)

.ValueAxis(axis => axis

    .Numeric()

    .Min(0)

    .Max(100)

    .Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0:n0}%"))

)

.Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip

    .Visible(true)

    .Template("#= series.name #: #= kendo.format('{0:n2}', value) #")

)
```

)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old but this might help the next person because Telerik's documentation wont.

In your foreach you need to pass the the column builder an IEnumerable class and then tell it which field is the category and which is the value:

```
    public class KendoStackedColumnModel
    {
        public string StackName { get; set; }
        public string Colour { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<KendoColumnModel> Columns { get; set; }

        public class KendoColumnModel
        {
            public decimal Value { get; set; }
            public string Category { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

And in the foreach:

```
    series.Column(stacked.Columns).CategoryField("Category").Field("Value").Name(stacked.StackName).Color(stacked.Colour);
```